# change color of text in clickable box

Tags: css, text, colors, clickable

I want to change the color of the text (link) in a box. This is the CSS code I'm using:

```
.boxed-1 {
    background-color: #e8ecf4;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
```

When I call for div class `boxed-1`, all the text displays blue. How can I change it?

I've tried a bunch of different suggestions from my google search to no avail.

My site is: http://mikediane.com

Answer (score 1):

Links are set to the color blue by the browser, thus they do not inherit from their parent like most other elements do.

You will need to apply a `color: #??????` to the `a` itself, like this:

```
.boxed-1 a {
    color: #??????;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/medC4/) for a demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you want to set the text in an element just apply the CSS style color.
In your case,

```
.boxed-1 {
   color: /*Whatever color you want*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your anchor tag's color is being applied to the text. If you create a rule like

```
.boxed-1 a { color: #hexcode; }
```

I'd expect this to work.